# SpringBoot WebFlux - Making parallel WebClient requests

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make parallel (batch) calls to the same rest service using the new SpringBoot 2 Reactive WebClient class(it does not have a batch endpoint). For example I need 100 "Comment" object (with ids 1...100) and I'm doing the following parallel calls :

```
    List<Mono<Comment>> monos = ids.stream()
            .map(id -> webClient.get()
                    .uri("/comments/{id}", id)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Comment.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return Flux.merge(monos);
```

I'm new to Spring WebFlux and I'm not sure this is the right way of doing parallel calls with the WebClient

- Is there a better(more appropriate) way of doing this (i.e. doing a
  Flux concat of Monos) ?
- Also, when I do this the old deprecated AsyncRestTemplate I use a
  ThreadPoolExecutor... Should I used a similar concept with the
  WebClient ? ... Is there something similar with reactive ?

Regards

The full source code can be bound at : https://github.com/fdlessard/SpringBootReactiveComment

Comment: concat will send requests in sequence, not in parallel: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-. merge will do that: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-

Answer (score 2):

```
Flux.fromIterable(ids)
  .flatMap(id -> webClient.get()
    .uri("/comments/{id}", id)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Comment.class))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
```

Comment: scheduling work on `Schedulers.paralell` is counter-productive here; the parallel scheduler is made for CPU-bound work, whereas making http calls is likely to be latency-bound. Parallelism happens naturally with reactive streams, since the consumer `request` a number of items depending on its capacity.

Comment: Sometimes you need to solve a problem that originally isn't a stream, so you'll convert into stream and process each item on parallel. You can use Flux so apply the parallel method and you should pass the scheduler you desire for instance: elastic, parallel, single, etc it will depend the problem you need to solve